# D3.js making a bar chart where x axis represents date and y axis represents times slept that day

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to make a chart of sleeping sessions that looks something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNbEm.jpg

Right my chart seems to only be plotting one of my days/data points. I've tried a bunch of things but nothing so far seems to make it draw rectangles for the rest of the days in the dataset. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Here's what my messed up chart looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkzHb.png

And here is the code that's drawing the chart:

```
// y domain is 24 hours
var yScale = 
    d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0,23])
    .range([chartArea.height, 0])
    .nice();

var yAxis = svg
    .append("g")
    .classed("yAxis", true)
    .attr(
        'transform', 'translate(' + padding.left+','+padding.top+')'
    );
var yAxisFn = d3
    .axisLeft(yScale)
    .ticks(24);

yAxisFn(yAxis);

// x domain is dates of data
var xScale = d3
    .scaleBand()
    .domain(sleepArr.map((d) => d.date))
    .range([0, chartArea.width])
    .padding(.2);

var xAxis = svg
    .append("g")
    .classed("xAxis", true)
    .attr(
        'transform', 'translate('+padding.left+','+(chartArea.height + padding.top)+')'
    )
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

var rectGrp = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' +padding.left+','+padding.top+')')
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(sleepArr)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
        .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
        .attr("height", (d) => chartArea.height - d.sessions[0].startTime.getHours())
        .attr("x", (d) => xScale(d.date))
        .attr("y", (d) => d.sessions[0].startTime.getHours())
        .attr("fill", (d) => colors[getDayOfWeek(d.date)])
        .append("title")
        .text((d) => d.date);
```

Comment: Is it rendering only one svg rect when you inspect it using the dev tools? One of your issues appears to be your xScale set up. Could it be you need to go one level deeper in your mapping?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's actually rendering all the rectangles, but putting them all in the same place. Oddly, it seems to be giving them all the same height/y value even though the data doesn't all have the same value (although most of them are the same value).